# Streaming to built in speakers and bluetooth speakers simultaneously

Tags: android, bluetooth

On Android, is it possible to *stream audio* to both a *bluetooth paired speaker* and the built in *speaker* at the same time?

Looking at `AudioManager`, it seems not to be the case. I thought there might be a way to do it via `MediaRouter`, but I can't find any documentation to point me in the right direction.

If anyone has any suggestions, it would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that even if you are able to do this, you will have synchronization problems.  The Bluetooth device will have a slightly different buffer size than the built-in sound interface.  This may not matter for your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can used `AudioManager.STREAM_RING`. This property sets to `MediaPlayer`:

```
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
```

is ready.

**BUT!** you really will have a problem with synchronization of Bluetooth device. Now i'm trying to solve it.