# MediaPlayer delay 0.4 seconds for Bluetooth headset

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm developing an application with playing audio. In several cases I change the  `AudioStreamType`  to  `AudioManager.STREAM_RING`(is mode when music is playing both: speakers and headset). When I use Bluetooth headset, I have a small annoying delay.

So i was reading that Bluetooth has a buffer and and this is logical
, but how I can solve this? Also i tried to change buffer size or delay for `mediaPlayer`.

So, i create a `mediaPlayer` like as:

```
@Override
public void onInit() {
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING); 
    songManager = new SongsManager(context);
}

@Override
public void onPrepare() {
    // prepare media player
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
        absolutePathToPlayingSong = /*some place*/;
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(/*some place*/);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.setVolume(volumeLvl, volumeLvl);
    }

    AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audio.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 20, 0);
}
```

then i just start player:

```
mediaPlayer.start();
```

So, i already tried:

1. to change a `prepare()` to `prepareAsync()` - probably it was tiny help, to may be i had a sound hallucinations. Unfortunately it broke a `seekTo()` in one place
2. added `onPrepared()` and start playing from listener - I not sure that it help

Give me please any advance^ how to fix delay for Bluetooth headset? I checked this device in YouTube application and it work great. So problem in my application. sorry my bad English!)

I have 2 target devices android 7.0(SDK 24) and android 4.2 (SDK 16)

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034198/streaming-to-built-in-speakers-and-bluetooth-speakers-simultaneously).

Comment: Probably somebody it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42582893/7449805
I can't used it, because my API < 24